# Show that the statement in the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity can be written (as Gauss did as)

Tags: number-theory

Show that the statement in the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity can be written (as Gauss did as)

$(\frac{p}{q})=(\frac{q \times (-1)^\frac{q-1}{2}}{p})$.

One is this question correct?

Second if it is wrong? If it is right then how do the proof?

$(\frac{p}{q})=(-1)^\frac{q-1}{2}(\frac{q}{p})$

Proof:

$(\frac{p}{q})=(\frac{p \times 1}{q})=(\frac{p}{q}) \times (\frac{1}{q})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of Quadratic Reciprocity as saying that for odd primes $p$ and $q$, we have $(p/q)=(q/p)$ unless both $p$ and $q$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. In that case, $(p/q)=-(q/p)$.

Now let us see whether the formula of the post does the same thing. Recall that $(-1/p)=1$ if $p$ is of the form $4k+1$, while $(-1/p)=-1$ if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$.

Let $q=4k+1$. Then we know $(p/q)=(q/p)$. The formula of the post gives $(p/q)=(q(-1)^{2k}/p)$, which is correct.

Let $q=4k+3$. Then the formula of the post gives $(p/q)=(-q/p)$. But $(-q/p)=(-1/p)(q/p)$. If $p$ is of the form $4l+1$, this gives the correct result $(q/p)$. If $p$ is of the form $4l+3$, then again we get the correct result $-(q/p)$.